# How could I parse the XML into hash

Tags: ruby

I hope I can get the list of hashed like that.

Is there any gem can do me a favor ?

## Expected result

```
[
    {
     "prog_name": "TAIWAN CTA Index",
     "prog_id": 9
    },
    {
     "prog_name": "CTO CTA Index",
     "prog_id": 12
    },    
]
```

## Original input file source.xml

```
<prog>
  <prog_name>TAIWAN CTA Index</prog_name>
  <prog_id>9</prog_id>
</prog>
<prog>
  <prog_name>CTO CTA Index</prog_name>
  <prog_id>12</prog_id>
</prog>
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert XML into a hash in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150856/how-do-i-convert-xml-into-a-hash-in-rails)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230741/convert-a-nokogiri-document-to-a-ruby-hash/7488299#7488299

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html). Something like:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(<IO thing here>)
@doc.xpath('prog').map do |prog_element| 
  {
    'prog_name' => prog_element.xpath('prog_name').content,
    'prog_id' => prog_element.xpath('prog_id').content
  }
end
```

would do it for you.