# How to convert Nokogiri object to xml file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is the output i get how to convet this to a xml file. I have been breaking my head even to find out what the result is. Please help me to solve this as i am a new guy to rails.

```
[#<LinkedIn::Position::Resource:0x4a63e80 @position=#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2531fa0 name="position" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2531c
34 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2531bf8 name="id" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2531850 "252416522">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0
x253155c "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x253152c name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x253122c "Senior Software Engineer">]>,
 #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2531094 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2530f8c name="summary" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x253089c "Wor
king on Ruby on Rails">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2530308 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252ff6c name="start-date" children=[#<Nokog
iri::XML::Text:0x252fb58 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252fb28 name="year" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252f960 "2012">]>, #<
Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252f888 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252f84c name="month" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252f684 "1">]>,
 #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252f5ac "\n      ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252f4d4 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252f4a4 name="is-curre
nt" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252efb8 "true">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252ed6c "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252ed3c name=
"company" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252e694 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252e5ec name="id" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Tex
t:0x252e364 "203940">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252e28c "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252e25c name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::X
ML::Text:0x252e094 "AB Innovative Software Pvt. Ltd">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252dfa4 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252df68 nam
e="size" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252dd40 "51-200 employees">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252dc50 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Elem
ent:0x252dc20 name="type" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252d9f8 "Privately Held">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252d908 "\n        ">, #<Noko
giri::XML::Element:0x252d8d8 name="industry" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252d6e0 "Computer Software">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252d4d0
 "\n      ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252d2f0 "\n    ">]>>, #<LinkedIn::Position::Resource:0x4a63b80 @position=#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x25
31f1c name="position" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252c588 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252c444 name="id" children=[#<Nokogiri
::XML::Text:0x252bce8 "127229045">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252bb80 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252bb50 name="title" children=[#
<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252b1d8 "Software Engineer">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252ac08 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x252ab48 name="s
ummary" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2529c9c "Software Engineer">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2529900 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Elemen
t:0x2529858 name="start-date" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x252930c "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x25292dc name="year" children
=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x25287f0 "2011">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2528664 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x25285e0 name="month" ch
ildren=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2527cc8 "4">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2527530 "\n      ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2527440 "\n      ">, #<
Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2527410 name="end-date" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2527248 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2527218 n
ame="year" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2527050 "2012">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2526f78 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2526
f3c name="month" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2526d74 "1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2526a20 "\n      ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2526
948 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2526918 name="is-current" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2526738 "false">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::T
ext:0x2526654 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2526624 name="company" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2526138 "\n        ">, #<Nokogi
ri::XML::Element:0x252609c name="id" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2525a60 "11498">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2525898 "\n        ">, #<No
kogiri::XML::Element:0x2525868 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x25256a0 "Onward Technologies">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x25255c8
 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2525598 name="type" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x25253ac "Public Company">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML:
:Text:0x2525184 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2525118 name="industry" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2524f2c "Information Techn
ology and Services">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2524e54 "\n        ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2524e24 name="ticker" children=[#<Nokogiri::
XML::Text:0x2524b48 "ONWARD">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x25247f4 "\n      ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2524110 "\n    ">]>>]
```

**client.inspect out put is**

```
#<LinkedIn::Client:0x4a1a908 @csecret=\"jKf6ZYgf8JhMoIJ4\", @access_token=#<OAuth::AccessToken:0x4a1a2c0 @token=\"177ba9cd-3b8e-4776-a7f7-db3f60d6df68\", @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @secret=\"d4641509-703a-42ad-a42a-2bf9ac2a8d48\", @consumer=#<OAuth::Consumer:0x4a1a1d0 @secret=\"jKf6ZYgf8JhMoIJ4\", @key=\"cus7tde3g4pe\", @uri=#<URI::HTTPS:0x4a19450 URL:https://api.linkedin.com>, @options={:authorize_path=>\"/uas/oauth/authorize\", :scheme=>:header, :http_method=>:post, :proxy=>nil, :site=>\"https://api.linkedin.com\", :request_token_path=>\"/uas/oauth/requestToken\", :oauth_version=>\"1.0\", :signature_method=>\"HMAC-SHA1\", :access_token_path=>\"/uas/oauth/accessToken\"}, @http=#<Net::HTTP api.linkedin.com:443 open=false>>, @params={}>, @ctoken=\"cus7tde3g4pe\", @consumer=#<OAuth::Consumer:0x4a1a1d0 @secret=\"jKf6ZYgf8JhMoIJ4\", @key=\"cus7tde3g4pe\", @uri=#<URI::HTTPS:0x4a19450 URL:https://api.linkedin.com>, @options={:authorize_path=>\"/uas/oauth/authorize\", :scheme=>:header, :http_method=>:post, :proxy=>nil, :site=>\"https://api.linkedin.com\", :request_token_path=>\"/uas/oauth/requestToken\", :oauth_version=>\"1.0\", :signature_method=>\"HMAC-SHA1\", :access_token_path=>\"/uas/oauth/accessToken\"}, @http=#<Net::HTTP api.linkedin.com:443 open=false>>, @asecret=\"d4641509-703a-42ad-a42a-2bf9ac2a8d48\", @consumer_options={:authorize_path=>\"/uas/oauth/authorize\", :request_token_path=>\"/uas/oauth/requestToken\", :access_token_path=>\"/uas/oauth/accessToken\"}, @atoken=\"177ba9cd-3b8e-4776-a7f7-db3f60d6df68\">"
```

Comment: where did you get this xml from and how do you call nokogiri? Which object class is that?

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is what the procedure 1. client = LinkedIn::Client.new("wwww", "rrrr") 2.client.authorize_from_access(session[:atoken], session[:asecret])#.3.@profile = client.profile 4.puts @profile = client.profile.to_s all these are to get a linkedin profile information in rails. Please help me

Comment: please give me the output of `client.profile.class` and remove the `to_s`because that will definitifly destroy the ability to extract the xml from the profile.

Comment: Please refer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120344/how-to-convert-linkedin-client-in-rails-to-hash

Comment: I was helpless from this morning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh okay now I see... try this:

```
data = Hash.from_xml(client.profile.to_s)
```

hf...

Comment: I am sorry i get this error : #<REXML::ParseException: malformed XML: missing tag start

Comment: please post output of `client.profile.to_s` it might be malformed xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Please help me as i am a new guy to ror.

Comment: #<LinkedIn::Profile:0x4a81e08> is what the output of client.profile.to_s

Comment: ahhh okay then it makes sense because thats no xml ;) I will look up the class descriptipn and add an answer n some minutes

Comment: okay that didnt help pleas post output of `client.inspect` might add it as an edit to your post I think it will be long...

Comment: client.inspect gives this out put : #<LinkedIn::Client:0x4ae1850 @csecret="jKf6ZYgf8JhMoIJ4", @access_token=#<OAuth::AccessToken:0x4ae0b48 @t

Comment: davidb have you got the solution for the problem

Comment: davidb Please help me to resolve this, if you come accross the solution please do forward the same to antony@abinnovative.com

Comment: re.. but I think this wasnt the whole output of `c lient.inspect`, wasnt it?!

Comment: thanks for reply davidb i am sorry this is the output which is very lengthy one, so pasting that in question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Okay that isnt it too. Where did you get the content from that you postet in the first time? Because Im searchingg for a way to access it.

Comment: client.connections.inspect.to_s and client.profile.inspect.to_s