# how to search a particular string in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have out put like below and i want to search for a particular string and it's value how to do this in rails.

ex :  i want search for **Nokogiri::XML::Text** pattern and get all pattern matching **Nokogiri::XML::Text**

```
#<LinkedIn::Location:0x4a339e8 @doc=#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x2519cb8 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2519a0c name="per
son" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x25197f0 "\n  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x251970c name="`" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2
519124 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x25190f4 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2518bd8 "Bengaluru Area, India">]>, #<Nokog
iri::XML::Text:0x2518b00 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2518ad0 name="country" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2518680 "\n      ">, #
<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2518650 name="code" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2517fcc "in">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2517eb8 "\n    ">]>,
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2517cd8 "\n  ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2517bdc "\n">]>]>>
```

Comment: I think you can parse nokogiri response further either and at the end u can use to_s or api methods that can help u to find out value.

Comment: Amar thanks for the response i have been trying to what you have commented for two days but ended up getting nothing. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122342/how-to-convert-nokogiri-object-to-xml-file-in-rails please see the above question's discussion for further information

Comment: In what way you are parsing can u give me the idea what u are doing might be i checked locally

Comment: i don't even know how to parse this. when i put client.profile.to_s than i get the above output but when i try to print client.profile than the out put i get is <LinkedIn::Profile:0x4a81e08> so don't know how to proceed further. please help.

Comment: don't use to_s doc=client.profile and then traverse children recursive way on each node check node.class == Nokogiri::XML::Text then do to_s and save result into some variable or in this case node also has children so traverse those children.Which gem u are using for fetching linked in profile

Comment: thanks i will check it , i am using linkedin gem to get user profile. i am sorry to ask you could you provide some sample if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value like :

Way-1 :

```
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(xml)
reader.read #Moves to next node in document
reader.attribute("cdn") # To get the value of attributes
```

Way-2 :

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
elems = doc.xpath("//*[@messageId]") #get all elements with an attribute of 'messageId'
elems[0].attr('messageId') #gets value of attribute of first elem
```

Comment: undefined method `empty?' for #<LinkedIn::Profile:0x49ae9f8> this is the error i get

Comment: I am sorry Vik i was on leave

Comment: I am not seeing any code of Nokogiri , you are using Xpath to parse xml . Wanting to suggest you that get the xml and try to parse it on console with Nokogiri .