# Any string to XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, libxml2

I am trying to convert a random string (which is build in XML format) in to an xml, so I can apply the "to_hash" function to it.

This is what I have:

```
model = live_requests[3]
parser = XML::Parser.string(model)
model_xml = parser.parse

puts model.to_hash
```

Now why am I getting an error when 'model_xml' should be an XML file?

I am using LibXML by the way.
http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html

Comment: What is your input? What is the error? Can you provide a little more information on *why* you want to do this? You'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Libxml does not support the `to_hash` method. If you are looking for a way to do this that doesn't require traversing XML nodes and bulding the hash manually you should take a look at [`Nori`](https://github.com/savonrb/nori).

```
Nori.parse("<tag>This is the contents</tag>")
# => { 'tag' => 'This is the contents' }
```

If you want to learn how to traverse Libxml's node trees take a look at [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230741/convert-a-nokogiri-document-to-a-ruby-hash).