# convert xml to utf-8 encoding

Tags: ruby, xml, encoding

I have an xml that starts with

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-8'?>
```

when I attempt to do

Hash.from_xml(my_xml)

I get a  `#<REXML::ParseException: No close tag for /root/response/message> (REXML::ParseException)`

in the message tag there is indeed characters in the above encoding. I need to parse that XML, so I am guessing that I need to convert it all to utf-8 or something else that the parse will like.

Is there a way to do this? (other uses like with Nokogiri are also good)

Answer (score 2):

Nokogiri seems to do the right thing:

```
# test.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-8'?>
<what>
  <body>דה</body>
</what>

xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read 'test.xml')
puts xml.at_xpath('//body').content
# => "דה"
```

You can also tell Nokogiri what encoding to use (e.g., `Nokogiri::XML(File.read('test.xml'), nil, 'ISO-8859-8')`), but that doesn't seem to be necessary here.

If that doesn't help, you might want to check that your XML is well-formed.

You can then convert the XML to UTF-8 if you like:

```
xml2 = xml.serialize(:encoding => 'UTF-8') {|c| c.format.as_xml }
```

If you just want to convert your Nokogiri XML to a hash, take a look at some of the solutions here: [Convert a Nokogiri document to a Ruby Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230741/convert-a-nokogiri-document-to-a-ruby-hash), or you can just do: `Hash.from_xml(xml2)`.