# ruby converting nokogiri xml to hash

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to convert  XML  with Nokogiri to a  hash:

```
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2016-05-01 11:38:14</currentTime>
  <result>
    <characterID>93898118</characterID>
    <characterName>Ghitzarai</characterName>
    <race>Minmatar</race>
    <bloodlineID>4</bloodlineID>
    <bloodline>Brutor</bloodline>
    <ancestryID>24</ancestryID>
    <ancestry>Slave Child</ancestry>
    <corporationID>98012663</corporationID>
    <corporation>Dry Atomic Fusion</corporation>
  </result>
</eveapi>

# asume xml is the above XML
hash = {}
xml.xpath('//result').each do |row|
  hash[get_node_name:] = row.content
end
```

Now `row.name` won't work cause that only returns `result` once.

How do I get the right names from the child nodes?

Comment: I just notised the lenght of xml.xpath('//result') is onyl 1. so also the question arises is how to loop over the childs

Comment: Use `...xpath('//result/*')...` ?

Comment: Aah, yes that works. thanks a lot!

Comment: converted my comment to answer with a brief explanation of what the XPath do exactly

Comment: See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10144623/405017) to [Convert a Nokogiri document to a Ruby Hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230741/convert-a-nokogiri-document-to-a-ruby-hash?rq=1) for a small-yet-robust implementation for serializing any Nokogiri document to a Hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"now `row.name` wont work cause that only returns result once. How to get the right names from the child nodes?"*

Add `/*` after `result` to get *all* child elements of `<result>` regardless of the child element name :

```
xml.xpath('//result/*').each do |row|
```